# What is the correct format for posting data?

Tags: xml, silverlight, post, format

I need to post a few pieces of data in a single form post from my silverlight app. Something like "Status=Complete,ID=xxx". What would be the most correct way to format this? Is it alright to just post an xml string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course XML is fine as well a many others in your particular example ) BUT if you are using or going to use another formats to transfer different kind of data - it is better to think about choosing universal format for all of them.